# How do I set the default values for `Python Integrated Tools` in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, settings

I am a regular PyCharm user. For most of my project I use:

- `pytest` as "Default test runner"
- `Google` as "Docstring format"

However, when I create a new project, I get as a default values:

- `Unittests` as "Default test runner"
- `reStructuredText` as "Docstring format"

and I have to manually set them to the above.
Hence, I would like this to be done automatically for new projects.

How do I change the default values for these so that, when I create a new project, I get the values I fancy better?

I use PyCharm 2019.1 (Community Edition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set default settings at:

File -> Other Settings -> Settings for New Projects

**Edit**: For the current version of PyCharm (2019.2) it is not possible to change the default *Python Integrated Tools* settings. See this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20243). It should be available in version 2019.3.

Comment: There seems to be no entry for the *Python Integrated Tools* in there.